# Basu's Theorem's application

Tags: statistics, random-variables, statistical-inference

I can't solve a problem, for which I am suppose to use Basu's theorem. Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent Exponential random variables with common parameter $\lambda$. I have to show that $X + Y$ and $\frac X{X + Y}$ are independent.
Can you help me on this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $X+Y$ is a complete sufficient statistic of the mean $\lambda$ (twice the mean, actually) and $Z=X/(X+Y)$ is an ancillary statistic since its distribution does not depend on $\lambda$. From [Basu's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basu%27s_theorem), it follows that these statistics are independent.

More direct approaches are possible, for example to compute the joint distribution of $(X+Y,Z)$ using a simple change of variables formula.

Comment: I am curious: what are your sources on Basu? Do these include the WP page I linked to?

Comment: It is obvious that $X+Y$ is boundedly complete as well?

Comment: @StefanHansen Completeness stems, for example, from the injectivity of Laplace transform.

Comment: Thanks a lot! My source on Basu is Mukhopadhyay textbook "Probability and Statistical inference" on which I studied it. I had not read the WP page.

Comment: @Did: Thanks.${}$